# Complex differentiation - Quotient Rule

Tags: complex-analysis, derivatives, complex-numbers

I've been given the following statement for the Quotient Rule:
Suppose $U \subseteq \mathbb{C} $ is open, $c \in U$ and both $f:U \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ and $g:U \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ are differentiable at $c$. Provided $g(c) \neq 0$, $\frac{f}{g}$ is differentiable at $c$ and $(\frac{f}{g})'(c) = \frac{g(c)f'(c)-f(c)g'(c)}{(g(c))^2}$

I am unsure why it is specified that $g$ is nonzero at only $c$. Surely it should be required that $g$ is nonzero everywhere on $U$, or else the function $\frac{f}{g}:U \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ wouldn't be well defined. Is this not stated because it's obvious, or is not stated because it's not required? And if it is not required, then why is this the case? I've checked several different sources and it's only every specified that $g$ is nonzero at $c$ and never anywhere else.

Edit: Thank you both for your answers! I understand now why only $g$ being nonzero at $c$ is required.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are right. However, if $g$ is differentiable at $c$, then it is continuous at $c$. So, since $g(c)\ne0$, there is some $r>0$ such that $z\in D_r(c)\cap U\implies g(z)\ne0$. Therefore, although $\frac fg$ may indeed not defined on the whole $U$, it is defined on some open neighborhood of $c$. And on that neighborhood the Quotient Rule is valid.

Answer (score 4):

If $g$ is differentiable at $c$ then it is continuous at $c$.

If $g$ is non-zero at $c$ and continuous at $c$, then it is non-zero in a neighborhood of $c$, so $f/g$ is defined in a neighborhood of $c$ too. And we don't need $f/g$ to be defined on all of $U$ for it to be differentiable at $c$, just in a neighborhood of $c$.

So, in summary, we can reach the desired conclusion of the argument with a weaker condition than what you expected (i.e. $g$ non-zero on all of $U$), and that weaker condition is implied by the assumptions that you see being made in your sources (i.e. $g$ differentiable and non-zero at $c$).